# React Hook not opening form onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to refactor from class based to functional. While doing so I will need to use hooks instead of setting this.state etc.. I am trying to get a FORM to open when i click a button. The button will also change from "add reply" to "submit comment" once the form opens. I am stumped. This is the best thing I could come up with... Doesnt work. in fact, it makes my "add reply" button completely disappear. Any thoughts on this? Here is the code that I have written. inside of the comment I am trying to return a  component using ternary....

[image of component as-is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q43m.png)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import FormOpen from './FormOpen';


const CommentCreated = (props) => {  

  const [resource, setResource] = useState([{visible: false, addReply: 'Add Reply'}]);

      return (
        <div className="ui threaded comments">
          <h3 className="ui dividing header">Comments</h3>
          <div className="comment">
            <a href="/" className="avatar">
                    <img alt="avatar" src= {props.avatar} />
              </a>
            <div className="content">
              <a href="/" className="author">{props.author}
                </a>
              <div className="metadata">
                <span className="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
              </div>
              <div className="text">{props.content}
              </div>
              <div className="actions">

              {resource.visible ? <FormOpen />  : null}

               <a className="reply" onClick={() => {setResource([{visible: true, addReply: 'Submit Comment'}]);}}>{resource.addReply}
                </a>
                <a className="save">Save</a>
                <a className="hide">Hide</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
   };

export default CommentCreated;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `setResource(['Submit Comment', true])` with :

```js
setResource([{
    visible: true,
    addReply: 'Submit Comment'
}])
```

To match the shape of your state.

**EDIT:**

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-brook-1gsyr?file=/src/App.js) based on your code.
As I can see from your example, your resource state doesn't need to be an array but simply an object.
Furthermore, as you are using hyperlinks `<a />`, you must use `preventDefault()` on your event being triggered if you don't want the page to refresh.

Comment: Darn, that seemed like it was going to work. Still no luck. In fact, the console is complaining still that <FormOpen /> isn't even being used. But it was doing this in both cases.

Comment: Can you please provide a full example of your code so that I can try to understand more simply your problems ?

Comment: unreal! Thank you very much! Why did I think that useState needed to be an array? as soon as I made that single change it worked. However, I like your implementation much better and will be studying the differences tonight. Thanks a ton I was losing my mind over this